# Swiftui Getting data from a nested json struct

Tags: json, struct, swiftui, nested

I am trying to access data from a nested json for a detailview, and get this error "Cannot convert value of type 'PeoplesPage' to expected argument type 'UserPeople" below is my code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PeoplesPageAPIResult: Codable {
    let data: [PeoplesPage]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "results"
    }
}


struct PeoplesPage: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var profileimage: URL
    var bgimage: URL
    var profilename: String
    var profilewatchers: String
    let peopleuser: [UserPeople]
}


struct UserPeople: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var userprofileimage: URL
    var userprofilename: String
    var userprofilecomments: String
}
```

_________ end PeoplesPage page ____________

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct PeopleComments: View {
    //E-MARK: - Properties
    var myuserpeps: UserPeople
```

//What i need to run var myuserpeps: PeoplesPage so i can access  UserPeople array from PeoplesPage

```
    //E-MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 5) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    WebImage(url: myuserpeps.userprofileimage)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .padding(5)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text(myuserpeps.userprofilename)
                            .font(.caption2)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)

                        Text(myuserpeps.userprofilecomments)
                            .font(.caption2)
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

_________ end PeopleComments page ____________

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct PeopleLiveView: View {
    //E-MARK: - Properties
    @EnvironmentObject var peoplesData: PeoplesPageViewModel
    
    //E-MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            
            if let peoplesData = peoplesData.livepeople {
                ForEach(peoplesData) { uppy in
                    PeopleComments(myuserpeps: uppy)
            }
            } else {
                ProgressView()
                    .padding(.top, 20)
            }
            
           
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
    }
}
```

_________ end PeopleLiveView page ____________

I can access the main PeoplesPage array, my problem is to access the nested array "let peopleuser: [UserPeople]" check above for clarity.

Thanks in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

class PeoplesPageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var livepeople: [PeoplesPage]? = nil
    
    
    init() {
            self.fetchmypeople()
    }
    
    func fetchmypeople() {
        
        let url = "my api url"
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in

            if let error = err{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let APIData = data else {
                print("No Data found")
                return
            }

            do {
                let newlivepeople = try JSONDecoder().decode(PeoplesPageAPIResult.self, from: APIData)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.livepeople = newlivepeople.data
                }
            }
            catch{

                print(error)
            }
    }
        .resume()
    }
    
}
```

_________ end PeoplesPageViewModel page ____________

Sample Json data

```
{
      "id": "0",
      "profileimage": "URL",
      "bgimage": "URL",
      "profilename": "name",
      "profilewatchers": "73.9K",
      "peopleuser": [
          {
          "id": "0",
          "userprofileimage" : "URL",
          "userprofilename" : "NAME",
          "userprofilecomments" : "Keep Shining, pal.",
          },
         {
          "id": "1",
          "userprofileimage" : "URL",
          "userprofilename" : "NAME",
          "userprofilecomments" : "Keep Shining, pal.",
          }

     ]
  }
```

Comment: Your exceeding usage of ***people*** is pretty confusing. What is `peoplesData.livepeople`?

Comment: @vadian its coming from the ViewModel, I will Edit my question and include both it and a sample of the returned json data

Comment: Done @vadian. The essense of this question is to access the data from the " peopleuser array "

Comment: your naming convention is so confusing that you are probably confusing yourself about what is an array and what type you are passing to functions and views. eg from `PeopleLiveView` to `PeopleComments`